# SymPy gives wrong answer to a simple linear system?

Tags: python, sympy

The code is

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x0:5')
linsolve([x[0]-x[2], x[4]-x[3]], x)
```

This is supposed to give something like

```
(x2, x1, x2, x4, x4)
```

as the answer, but instead it gives

```
(x1, x1, x2, x4, x4)
```

I also tried the live.sympy.org online shell which also gives this same wrong answer.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

At least it is consistent. `x1`, as it does not appear in the equation set is like a constant and if both `x0` and `x2` are equal to that constant then the first equation will be satisfied. The result from `solve` might be preferred:

```
>>> solve([x[0]-x[2], x[4]-x[3]], x)
{x3: x4, x0: x2}
```